# Kivy: How to render 3D model in a given layout

Tags: python, canvas, layout, kivy, rendering

I am trying to make a simple 3D model viewer. I started from 3Drendering example, one of the kivy examples. Following is the test code I tried.(Python 3.7, Kivy 1.11.1)

Python code: test_renderer.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from renderer import Renderer
from kivy.lang import Builder
#from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
#from kivy.uix.label import Label
#from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_file('test_win.kv')


class Test_Win(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Test_Renderer(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Test Renderer'
        return Test_Win()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test_Renderer().run()
```

and kv file: test_win.kv

```
# File name: test_win.kv
#:kivy 1.11.1

<Test_Win>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Test Renderer'
            Button:
                text: 'Click'
        Splitter:
            Renderer:
```

The other files(renderer.py, objloader.py, simple.glsl, monkey.obj) from the 3Drendering example(main.py, objloader.py, simple.glsl, monkey.obj) are same except name change of main.py to renderer.py, which are all in the same folder as the above two files.

These files can be found at 
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__3Drendering__main__py.html#

or at https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/3Drendering with a 3D file.

The resulting screen is [as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuNRH.png)

The rotating head is displayed on the top of the layout and widgets. It looks that the display canvas is that of root, not the splitter layout as I intended.

I just started kivy and have no idea where to start. Can anyone help me find the solution?

Comment: An important note is that the `Canvas` (misleading name) is just a list of graphics instructions. It is your responsibility to adjust the position and scale of your triangles to place them where you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I understand that. But unlike other widgets(including layout), the Renderer class behaves independantly of the layout. For example, when I replace Renderer: with Label:, it follows the layout I set. I don't know how to incorporate the canvas of the Renderer class into the layout.

Comment: The 3D rendering is done using the `Canvas` of a `Widget`. It could be dome using the `Canvas` of any `Widget`. In fact, everything you see in your `App` is done via the `Canvas`. The only reason that the `Widgets` appear where you expect them to be is because the designers have carefully crafted the `Canvas` instructions of each `Widget` to make that happen. Try experimenting with a `Rectangle` on any `Canvas`, and modify its `pos` and `size`. You will see that the  `Rectangle` `pos` is only related to the `Widget` `pos` if you make it so.

Comment: An exception to my above statement is the `Relative` `Layout`, where all positions are relative to the position of the `Layout`. So you might consider using a `RelativeLayout` as the basis of your renderer. But the drawing `Canvas` of the `RelativeLayout` is still not restricted to its area.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a hack to do almost what you want. Because projection matrices are involved it is a bit complicated. Perhaps someone more versed in OGL could do a better job. Here is my hack:

First, I wanted the extents of the 3D object, so I modified the `__init__()` method of the `ObjFile` class:

```
def __init__(self, filename, swapyz=False):
    """Loads a Wavefront OBJ file. """
    self.objects = {}
    self.vertices = []
    self.normals = []
    self.texcoords = []
    self.faces = []
    maxf = sys.float_info.max

    # initialize the minimums and maximums
    self.mins = [maxf, maxf, maxf]
    self.maxs = [-maxf, -maxf, -maxf]

    self._current_object = None

    material = None
    for line in open(filename, "r"):
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        if line.startswith('s'):
            continue
        values = line.split()
        if not values:
            continue
        if values[0] == 'o':
            self.finish_object()
            self._current_object = values[1]
        # elif values[0] == 'mtllib':
        #    self.mtl = MTL(values[1])
        # elif values[0] in ('usemtl', 'usemat'):
        #    material = values[1]
        if values[0] == 'v':
            v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
            if swapyz:
                v = v[0], v[2], v[1]

            # keep the vertex minimums and maximums
            for i in range(3):
                self.mins[i] = min(self.mins[i], v[i])
                self.maxs[i] = max(self.maxs[i], v[i])


            self.vertices.append(v)
        elif values[0] == 'vn':
            v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
            if swapyz:
                v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
            self.normals.append(v)
        elif values[0] == 'vt':
            self.texcoords.append(map(float, values[1:3]))
        elif values[0] == 'f':
            face = []
            texcoords = []
            norms = []
            for v in values[1:]:
                w = v.split('/')
                face.append(int(w[0]))
                if len(w) >= 2 and len(w[1]) > 0:
                    texcoords.append(int(w[1]))
                else:
                    texcoords.append(-1)
                if len(w) >= 3 and len(w[2]) > 0:
                    norms.append(int(w[2]))
                else:
                    norms.append(-1)
            self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoords, material))
    self.finish_object()
    print('max :', self.maxs, ', mins:', self.mins)
```

And in the `Renderer` class, I modified two methods:

```
def update_glsl(self, delta):
    # Calculate new left edge for the clip matrix
    old_scene_width = self.scene.maxs[0] - self.scene.mins[0]
    app_width = App.get_running_app().root.width
    renderer_width = self.width
    ratio = app_width / renderer_width
    new_scene_width = old_scene_width * ratio
    left = self.scene.mins[0] - (new_scene_width - old_scene_width)

    # calculate new top and bottom of clip frustum that maintains monkey head aspect ratio
    scene_center_vertical = (self.scene.mins[1] + self.scene.maxs[1]) /  2.0
    old_scene_height = self.scene.maxs[1] - self.scene.mins[1]
    new_scene_height = old_scene_height * ratio
    bottom = scene_center_vertical - new_scene_height / 2.0
    top = scene_center_vertical + new_scene_height / 2.0

    # create new clip matrix
    proj = Matrix().view_clip(left, self.scene.maxs[0],
                              bottom, top,
                              1, self.scene.maxs[2] - self.scene.mins[2] - self.translate.z,
                              1)

    self.canvas['projection_mat'] = proj
    self.canvas['diffuse_light'] = (1.0, 1.0, 0.8)
    self.canvas['ambient_light'] = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    self.rot.angle += delta * 100

def setup_scene(self):
    Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
    PushMatrix()

    # save a reference to the Translate matrix
    self.translate = Translate(0, 0, -3)

    self.rot = Rotate(1, 0, 1, 0)
    m = list(self.scene.objects.values())[0]
    UpdateNormalMatrix()
    self.mesh = Mesh(
        vertices=m.vertices,
        indices=m.indices,
        fmt=m.vertex_format,
        mode='triangles',
    )
    PopMatrix()
```

The idea is to adjust the clipping matrix so that the monkey head is centered in the `Renderer` `Widget`. To accomplish that, I have modified the `left` parameter of the clip matrix such that the monkey head is no longer in the center of the clipping frustum. I also re-calculated the `top` and `bottom` parameters of the frustum in order to avoid uneven scaling (distortion).

Comment: This is a great answer! I tried your code and it works as expected. I cannot thank you enough. It's a good starting point to make a more complete 3D viewer of my own. I really appreciate that.